# Javascript function works for a while, then freezes the browser

Tags: javascript

I'm using this JS code to make a banner:

```
var images = ["../../images/g11.jpg","../../images/g9.jpg","../../images/g10.jpg"];
var titulos = ["title1","title2","title3"];
var resumos = ["ddd","aaa","bbb"];
var noticias = ["190","204","200"];

var total = 3;
var indice = 0;

function rotate() {
    document.getElementById('imageb').src = images[indice];
    document.getElementById('titulob').innerHTML = titulos[indice];
    document.getElementById('resumob').innerHTML = resumos[indice];
    document.getElementById('noticiab').value = noticias[indice];
    indice++;
    if (indice > total - 1) indice = 0;
}

function banner() {
    rotate();
    setTimeout(banner, 5000);
}
```

It works how expected, but after some loops it freezes the browser. Pretty sure I'm not using setTimeout properly. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Working so far:

```
function rotate(indice) {
    document.getElementById('imageb').src = images[indice];
    document.getElementById('titulob').innerHTML = titulos[indice];
    document.getElementById('resumob').innerHTML = resumos[indice];
    document.getElementById('noticiab').value = noticias[indice];
}

function banner(indice) {
    var f1 = function() { banner(indice); };
    var total = 3;
    rotate(indice);
    indice++;
    if (indice > total - 1) indice = 0;
    setTimeout(f1, 5000);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to at the very least make `setTimeout(banner..)` into `setTimeout(function(){ banner() }, ...)`

Comment: @ Jairo: *"Pretty sure I'm not using setTimeout properly."* Looks right to me, if you want to call `banner` five seconds after the last time you called it.

Comment: I think it is a better way to make it clear for another person seeing his code, that its being called as a function, I didn't say it would solve his problem

Comment: @nrathaus: It's perfectly clear that `banner` is being called as a function. Which is just as well, as `banner` is a function, and you can't call anything but functions! :-)

Comment: @ Jairo: I can see ways I'd refactor that code, but I can't see any way it would freeze the browser. *Completely* on spec, I'd wrap the entire thing in a scoping function (just put `(function() {` at the top and `})();` at the bottom) in case there's some weird issue with creating those globals, but that's a *total* guess.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "you can't call anything but functions" -- for some reason I now want to find some obscure technicality to prove this wrong ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder As opposed to a half guess?

Comment: Do yo have some proof that this happens? Looking at the code there is nothing that should technically cause this to stall after a few calls.  As for the issue of "setTimeout can only take functions", no it can't. It can also get strings, in which case it does a ninja-eval (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I never said `setTimeout` could only take functions. I said you can only *call* functions. Quite right that if it weren't for being defined two lines above, there would be the vague possibility the `banner` symbol resolved to a variable containing a string. I guess that's what nrathaus meant.

Comment: @ Jairo: I'm not seeing it freeze up: http://jsbin.com/uJaTokIY/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/uJaTokIY/1/edit).

Comment: @ Jairo: Six minutes so far of updating every half second with your original code, no probs.

Comment: Indeed @T.J.Crowder, your example works fine here. I needed to kill the process several times. It was correct (to me). But now it works by using local variables. I gonna get the older code back and send the link.

Comment: the link is http://smtca.sp.gov.br/novo2/ , but it's not freezing anymore. Could it be a local problem?

Comment: @ Jairo: If you can't catch it freezing, and the assembled crowd here can't see why it would, I'd put it down to "one of those things." (My jsbin of your original code above is still happily running...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a CW because it's a total guess.

Completely FWIW, here's how I'd minimally change that code: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uJaTokIY/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/uJaTokIY/2/edit)

```
(function() {
    var entries = [
        {
            img:        "../../images/g11.jpg",
            titulo:     "title1",
            resumo:     "ddd",
            noticia:    "190"
        },
        {
            img:        "../../images/g9.jpg",
            titulo:     "title2",
            resumo:     "aaa",
            noticia:    "204"
        },
        {
            img:        "../../images/g10.jpg",
            titulo:     "title3",
            resumo:     "bbb",
            noticia:    "200"
        }
    ];

    var indice = 0;

    function rotate() {
        var entry = entries[indice];
        document.getElementById('imageb').src = entry.img;
        document.getElementById('titulob').innerHTML = entry.titulo;
        document.getElementById('resumob').innerHTML = entry.resumo;
        document.getElementById('noticiab').value = entry.noticia;

        indice = (indice + 1) % data.length;
    }

    function banner() {
        rotate();
        setTimeout(banner, 5000);
    }

    banner();
})();
```

Changes:

1. Put everything in a scoping function to avoid creating global variables.
2. Use an array of objects rather than parallel arrays.
3. Use the array's length rather than a separate `total` variable.
4. Use the remainder trick for getting the wrap-around on the `indice` variable.
5. I added a call to `banner();` at the end to get things started, but I assume you have that and just didn't show it.

But again, I don't see any reason your code shouldn't be working as is, other than the possibility of some weird global variable conflict.

Comment: I would use setInterval over setTimeout to ensure you are never rotating more than once at any given time.  While this doesn't look like a concern with a timeout of 5000 it does clarify the behavior of the code and guarantees this issue cant arise. It also makes stopping and starting the rotation animation much simpler.

Comment: @Deadron: But there's no way the above would cause overlapping rotations, using `setInterval` isn't needed to ensure that. We're quite clearly not scheduling the next run until the previous run completes. I'm not a big fan of `setInterval`. Some browsers measure the interval from when they *call* the callback, others from when it returns. I prefer chained `setTimeout`. But yes, absolutely, that's an option.

Comment: "Some browsers measure the interval from when they call the callback, others from when it returns. I prefer chained setTimeout" - wait what?

Comment: He is suggesting that some browsers wait until the function has finished to start the time delay to the next call while others will literally fire the function every time the interval is reached.  This seems undefined in the actual spec due to non specific language.  At the very least it should never attempt to call the function while one is currently executing is my understanding.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It's true, or at least it was last I checked (which I'll admit was probably four+ years ago -- and we know how much things have improved since then). Say you do `setInterval(foo, 1000)` and `foo` takes 250ms to run (exaggerated example). Some browsers will call `foo` ~1000ms after the last time they *initiated* a call to `foo`, and so `foo` runs every ~1000ms. Others schedule it more like the above, when `foo` returns, and so it ends up running every ~1250ms. But mostly I just like the control of saying "unless I reschedule it, it won't run again."

Comment: @Deadron of course it's specced. It's a specific API (the DOM timers API) (not to mention the language - JavaScript is specced, but is "irrelevant" here because it's a DOM API call) - here is the spec http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers . If you look at steps 2 and 3 you can clearly see that the order here is not ambiguous at all..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Which browsers are those? (I have the usual suspects), any citation or code reproducing this?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: This was before the behavior of `setTimeout` and `setInterval` was specified. :-) And I'm sorry to say I don't recall which ones it was, only that I was quite surprised by the behavior. I don't *think* it was IE, or at least not only IE, but I'd hate to speculate in the absense of memory. The other behavior that surprised me related to what happened if `foo` took more than 1000ms to run (again, exaggerated example). The behavior (reliably, I seem to recall) was to just skip the next interval entirely. I haven't checked what the nascent spec says about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My comment about vague language is exactly due to the fact that the way the spec is written it could start the interval at either point and still meet the definition.

Comment: The thing with chained timeouts is that you do something like `func() { stuffThatTakesTime(250); setTimeout(func, 1000) }` then `func` will run every 1250+ ms, and if you do `setInterval(func, 1000)` then it will be scheduled to run every 1000ms and it doesn't matter that func took 250ms to do stuff. Good explanation [here](http://pamoller.com/setTimeout-vs-setInterval.html). Not necessarily a reason to prefer setInterval either.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: Yes, if I want that behavior I put the `setTimeout` at the beginning of the function. :-) Chained `setTimeout` is more susceptible to delays between when the call to the callback is queued and when the thread is free to run it, though, I think. So *that* might be a reason to prefer `setInterval`, in some cases. (And aren't we all just a bunch of nerds?! :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, hmm, that does seem to help a lot. http://jsfiddle.net/da7xJ/ <- try reversing the values for `slowness` and `interval` and things get interesting (ignore the first timer in each set if you run it more than once).